# Can't Upload Img Using concrete view django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Hope You Are Fine!

How Can i Upload Img Using concrete view Django rest framework?

i have a model

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    maiden_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatar/', blank=True, null=True)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=124, blank=True, null=True)
    proposal_comments = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    associations = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    interests = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    website = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=124, blank=True, null=True)
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=124, blank=True, null=True)
    country = CountryField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

which had image field named profile_picture i have also registered this model to admin and when i upload img using django administration it automatically upload/added to media folder.

but when i upload img using django rest framework it is not showing me any error. what django rest framework do just update the url of img. django rest framework is not uploading/adding img to my media folder.

i'm uploading img by hand.

**settings.py**

```
....
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR.parent, "media")
MEDIA_URL = "/api/media/"
```

**urls.py**

```
.....
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "email", "first_name", "last_name",)
        read_only_fields = ("username",)

    def validate_email(self, email):
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).first() and User.objects.filter(id=self.context.get("request").user.id).first().email != email:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("* Email Already Exist!")

        if not email:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("* Email Adress is Required!")

        return email


class UserProfileSerializer(CountryFieldMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):

    user = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = "__all__"
        read_only_fields = ("username",)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        user_validated_data = validated_data.pop('user')
        profile = Profile.objects.filter(id=instance.id).update(**validated_data)
        user = User.objects.filter(id=instance.user.id).update(**user_validated_data)
        return Profile.objects.filter(id=instance.id).first()
```

**views.py**

```
class UserProfileRetrieveUpdateAPIView(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer

    def get_user_or_404(self):
        print(self.request.user.id)
        return get_object_or_404(User, id=self.request.user.id)

    def get_object(self):
        obj = get_object_or_404(Profile, user=self.get_user_or_404())
        return obj
```

can you please tell me what i'am doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: How are you uploading the image? From which interface?

Comment: @Paul if i upload img using django administration it work prefectly fine, but if i upload img using django rest framework it's not uploading img to media folder, i'm using web interference